# Spotlight lags for a second when first opened and typed in

Tags: macos, spotlight, apple-silicon, ventura

After spotlight lags, it will be running correctly (without lag when typing) for 10 minutes or more, but after a time, it will lag again.

I've tried reset index, but it not work for me.

Based:
Chip M1 Pro; macOS Ventura 13.2.1

The CPU and Memory usage when the lag happens:

[image: Activity Monitor - CPU]

[image: Activity Monitor - Memory]

Only CPU usage have changed (usually its usage is 0.0),the Memory usage is the same.

Comment: What's your overall RAM usage when this happens? I've found the M processors are very easy to bog down.

Comment: @Tetsujin I check the memory-used is 13g or so.And the lag will happen anytime, except that just after a lag, it will be right for a moment.But once I don't use spotlight for a while, it'll lag again

Comment: But if I paste instead of typing, it won't be a lag

Comment: Try keeping Activity Monitor open all the time - maybe shove it on an unused Space. Set View > All Processes, then sort by %CPU in the CPU column & Memory in Memory. When it happens, see if you can grab a quick screenshot of both.

Comment: @Tetsujin When the lag happens, the CPU usage is 50% and Memory usage is 4.6GB,the usual usage is 0.0 for CPU and 4.6GB for Memory

Comment: Something odd with both Spotlight & WindowServer there, taking pretty much a whole core CPU between them. I don't see either do more than a single time slice in the 'top ten' with maybe 10% each, then they vanish down the list again. Same in the memory list, they're both hammering the RAM. How long since last boot & how long since you cleared the index?

Comment: @Tetsujin 24 days since last reboot, and 4 days since last reindex

Comment: Then reboot, & don't clear the index again.

Comment: @Tetsujin It'll be right for a while, and then again.

Answer (score 2):

After I updated to the latest Ventura 13.3 recently, it doesn't lag anymore.